# Why does Gradle mark my build with failed tests as successful?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, spock

I have a Gradle build with failing tests, but Gradle does not register the build as failed. However, the build does correctly fail if I remove a specific test case. Why is that?

```
$ ./gradlew clean check

:clean
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:compileTestJava
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses
:test

com.example.FooProgramCliTest > fail FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError at FooProgramCliTest.java:26

1 test completed, 1 failed
:check

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Code sample [on GitHub](https://github.com/emlun/gradle-incorrectly-successful-build/tree/build-succeeds), because it's a bit too bulky to meaningfully reproduce in the question body.

Comment: What is the code of the unit test?

Comment: A bit too convoluted to show directly in the question, see the link I added to the question (it's the same as the one in my answer below).

Comment: Ok, if you already have the answer then you can accept your own answer so that this question do not appear "open". Is that the case?

Comment: Yes. I was holding off on accepting for a bit just in case any other answers drop in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your tests do not inadvertently cause `System.exit(int)` to be called. Doing so will prevent Gradle from registering the test failure. See [here](https://github.com/emlun/gradle-incorrectly-successful-build) for an example use case where this could happen.